# bash "&" without printing "[1]+ Done "

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I call a script in my .bashrc to print number of new messages I have when I open the terminal, I want the call to be non blocking as it accesses the network and sometimes takes a few seconds which means I can't use the terminal until it completes.

However if I put:

```
    mailcheck &
```

in my bashrc, it works fine. but then prints an empty line and I have when I press enter and it prints

```
    [1]+  Done                    ~/bin/mailcheck
```

This is very messy is there a way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That message isn't coming from mailcheck, it's from bash's job control telling you about your backgrounded job.  The way to avoid it is to tell bash you don't want it managed by job control:

```
mailcheck &
disown $!
```

Comment: Why not just `mailcheck & disown` ?

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work:

```
(mailcheck &)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can call your script like this:

```
(exec mailcheck & )
```

Comment: still no good I get:

        [1]+  Done                    exec ~/bin/mailcheck

Comment: It is working fine in my testing. When I include a script call in my .bashrc I don't get any `Done` message when I log-in next time.

Comment: @anubhava: Can I use this technique in my Bashrc to source all scripts in a given directory as follows: `List=(~/bin/Completion*); for File in "${List[@]}"; do (exec . "$File" &) done` But I get this error: `bash: exec: .: cannot execute: Is a directory`

Answer (score 2):

try piping stderr to /dev/null

```
mailcheck & 2>/dev/null
```

Thinking about it for a few mins, another way might be to use write.
Pipe the output of the background task to yourself, that way it can complete at any time and you can bin any additional output from stdout as well as stderr.

```
mailcheck | write $(whoami) & > /dev/null
```

Comment: No sorry should have said I tried that, it doesn't seem to be stderr

Comment: shouldn't be stderr because it's not an error. since it's running in the background it's just letting you know that the process has finished successfully. maybe stdout?

Comment: That's no good either, I don't understand this, if it's not stdout or stderr what is it?

Comment: hmm... the output isn't from the script itself so it wouldn't be stdout. well I'm not sure, but since you found the answer another way it's all good! :)

Comment: actually you still need to press enter as it hangs on a blank line is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the last page I checked before I fixed an issue I was having so I figured I would leave my finished script that had the same issue as OP:

```
nohup bash -c '{anycommand};echo "CommandFinished"' 1> "output$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M").out" 2> /dev/null & disown
```

This runs `{anycommand}` with `nohup` and sends the `stdout` to a unique file, the `stderr` to `/dev/null`, and the rest to console (the PID) for scraping. The `stdout` file is monitored by another process looking for the `CommandFinished` or whatever unique string.

Bash would later print this:

```
[1]+  Done                    nohup bash -c ....
```

Adding `disown` to the end stopped bash jobs from printing that to console.