# Killing a background process while building a bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt, background-process, kill

I have managed to make my bash prompt lazy loads some components to have the feeling of an async rendering. The lazy loading function runs as a background process with `(render_async &)`.

From the screencast below you can see how the prompt actually loads part of it right away and the other "lazy loads". However, what I noticed is that if you change the directory before the async part is loaded the new prompt gets overwritten with wrong context.

[image]

My thought process of fixing this is the following:

- Check for background process using the `jobs` command
- I discovered that the jobs command shows a `wd:*` next to processes that are not in the background of the current working directory
- Find all and kill all background processes that have that pattern to avoid this overwriting

I added a sleep to my async command to simulate that and I can see the background process hanging.

```
[1]   Running                 render_async &
[2]-  Running                 render_async &  (wd: ~/Projects/My Personal Space/blog-core)
[3]+  Running                 render_async &
```

I went ahead and wrote:

```
  jobs | grep 'render_async.*wd:' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1 | while read -r line ; do
    kill "%$line"
  done
```

Which in theory should parse the id of the background jobs in other directories and kill them. However in practice I keep getting for the example above `kill: %2: no such job`.

When I execute the same `kill` command in the shell itself it works perfectly.

Would appreciate any help here.

### Other thoughts

I have tried naming my forked process (name each async process by appending the CWD to the function name) inspired from https://askubuntu.com/questions/153900/how-can-i-start-a-process-with-a-different-name where:

> `bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName <command> &"`  replaces
>   the current shell, no new process is created, that's why I'm starting
>   a new shell to call exec.
>
> Then you can kill the process with:
>
> pkill -f MyUniqueProcessName You can start more than one process under
>   the same name, then pkill -f  will kill all of them.

but that kept telling me that my async function that I was trying to pass to the `<command>` is not found and I suspect it has something to do with the fact that it is a custom function and that is forking a new bash process but I am not an expert here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a terminal that provides a title window or other out-of-band location you can write status to? It's certainly going to be possible to *improve* this approach, but I'm not sure you'll ever be able to make it completely robust: If a new process thinks it owns the terminal but your old shell's subprocess is still printing, a conflict is inevitable.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy for your comment. I am using the MacOSX terminal but would love to see how i can improve this and make it robust

Comment: `while` makes an implicit subshell, as far as I know, so the `kill` in the while might not be able to see the jobs.

Comment: @cxw, no, `while` doesn't create a subshell; in piping to `while`, it's the pipe, not the `while`, responsible. (You're right, though, that it won't be the same shell instance and won't have the same job table; for noninteractive scripts one can use `lastpipe` to change that behavior, but it's not available with job control on).

Comment: @AhmadAssaf, ...btw, `exec -a MyUniqueProcessName bash -c '...'` can run functions you exported with `export -f`. Not that I'd call that an appropriate tool for the job at hand -- it's even higher-overhead than a regular subshell.

Comment: ...in general, when you start something from bash and want to kill it later, you should retain the pid: `foo & foo_pid=$!` lets you `kill "$foo_pid"` later (and check if it's still running with `if kill -0 "$foo_pid" &>/dev/null; then` or the like).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the correction!  Also, I like your `$!` idea - that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping creates an implicit subshell, so jobs from the parent are not visible inside the piped-to `while` loop where the `kill` is running.  How about this, which will at least kill the first job?

```
job="$(jobs | grep 'render_async.*wd:' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)"
kill "%$job"
```

In my tests, the `$(...)` happens in the current shell, at least initially, so the job table is visible.  Example:

```
$ cat &
[1] 8296
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ echo "$(jobs| cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1|head -1)"
1
```

(By the way, does the job you want to kill always have the same job number?  Can you just hardcode `%2`, or whatever it may be?)

**Edit** Multijob:

```
joblist="$(jobs| sed -E 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'|tr '\n' '@')"
    # E.g., 1@2@
IFS='@'     # Split on @
for job in $joblist     # No double-quotes!
do
    kill "%$job"
done
```

Working example from a shell prompt:

```
$ cat&
[1] 8824
$ cat&
[2] 6452

[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 cat
[2]+  Stopped                 cat
$ joblist="$(jobs| sed -E 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/'|tr '\n' '@')"
$ IFS=@
$ for job in $joblist; do kill "%$job" ; done

[1]-  Stopped                 cat

[2]+  Stopped                 cat
$ jobs
[1]-  Terminated              cat
[2]+  Terminated              cat
$ jobs
$
```

I chose `@` as a separator because I don't think it means anything particular to the shell.

I don't know if it makes a difference in the PS1-function environment.

Comment: The job number is dynamic and can change .. I will try your approach now :)

Comment: Even with your first approach i still get `-bash: kill: %: no such job`. I am not sure that the fact that I am executing this as my PS1 function has anything to do with it

Comment: ok interesting .. it seems that the problem is not access to the jobs table as when i hardcoded `kill %2` it worked and the job was killed. Doing that dynamically seem to be a problem

Comment: @AhmadAssaf Edited with multi-job support.  Unless the multi-job way works, would you please update your question with an MCVE?

Comment: the trick with the for did the job @cxw. It seems that the sub process of the while was the cuplrit. However, I am running now into maybe another problem. To suppress the status of the background job I am running it wrapped with brackets `(render_async &)` .. when I do that the kill is not happening but when i remove them everything works as expected. Any idea why ?

Comment: I think I know why. Referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439590/bash-without-printing-1-done this tells bash not to make the job managed by job control. I am a bit confused now

Comment: A `set -m` did the trick :) https://superuser.com/questions/305933/preventing-bash-from-displaying-done-when-a-background-command-finishes-execut